# Getting entities from pre-saved DocBin

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have around 700k documents that I want to process in spacy and save into a DocBin for later use.

I wrote a code to do a keywords search using phrasematcher and it worked great. I'm now trying to build a knowledge graph out of the DocBin I have and I can't seem to be able to access the entities to use them in the graph logic. I read somewhere that DocBins don't keep that information (?) but when I print DocBin.tokens I get some values and not just an empty output.

This might be a very stupid question but I'm quite lost and the documentation does not seem to be detailed enough for this.

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin
from spacy.vocab import Vocab

nlp = spacy.load('fr_dep_news_trf')
DocBinPath = r'C:\[Redacted]\FRdocBin.nlp'

loadedDocBin = DocBin(Vocab()).from_disk(DocBinPath)  

DocList=list(loadedDocBin.get_docs(nlp.vocab))
for doc in DocList
    People = list(set([ent.text for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_=='PERSON']))
```

This doesn't produce any errors but doc.ents is empty.

This is the code for saving the Docbin:

```
FRdoc_bin = DocBin (store_user_data=True,attrs=['ENT_TYPE','LEMMA','LIKE_EMAIL','LIKE_URL','LIKE_NUM','ORTH','POS','HEAD','DEP'])
doc = frNLP(text)
FRdoc_bin.add(doc)
FRdoc_bin.to_disk(CreatedModelPath+r'\FRdocBin'+'.nlp')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I figured out the issue from the spacy discussion, it's quite simply that the fr model I was using doesn't support NER. Switched `fr_core_news_lg` and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom `attrs`, you need both `ENT_IOB` and `ENT_TYPE` for entities.

Are you sure that you need custom `attrs` in the first place? Have you customized the values for `LIKE_URL` or other lexical attrs? If not, the default `attrs` for `DocBin` should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @aab ! I removed the custom attrs, I really don't need them but was rather trying to reduce the size. If it causes an additional headache I don't think it's worth it. But when I load the docbin again and loop over the documents, doc.ents still is empty